# iOS does not render SVG images in Ionic 3 project

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, ionic-framework, ionic3

I tried different solutions available in https://forum.ionicframework.com and https://stackoverflow.com but none resulted in svg image for iOS.

I am using svg images from https://thenounproject.com and images render on android phones and on web browser but not on iPhone.

Solutions I tried (all of which render for Android but not iPhone):

1) `src="assets/imgs/svg/halal.svg"`

2) `src="./assets/imgs/svg/halal.svg"`

3) added `type="image/svg+xml"` to  tag

4) added  `background-color: transparent;` to the  tag styling

Any solution that would work for iPhones?

## updated

```
<ion-col col-3 text-center><img type="image/svg+xml" src="./assets/imgs/svg/parking.svg" style="padding:7px;" /><p style="font-size:11px; ">Parking</p></ion-col>
<ion-col col-3 text-center><img type="image/svg+xml" src="./assets/imgs/svg/wheelchair.svg" style="padding:7px; background-color: transparent;" /><p style="font-size:11px; ">Wheelchain</p></ion-col>
<ion-col col-3 text-center><img type="image/svg+xml" src="./assets/imgs/svg/wifi.svg" style="padding:7px;" /><p style="font-size:11px; ">Wifi</p></ion-col>
```

This is what it looks like on IPhone

[image]

Comment: Please provide more context to your problem. A little bit of code can go a long way to help us debug the issue.

Comment: You also need to state which version(s) of iOS you're seeing issues. "IOS" and "Iphones" cover a broad spectrum.

Comment: @richbai90 does this help?

Comment: @AndréDion iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 7 Plus. ofcourse I want svg to be shown in entire spectrum or alteast most of it.

Comment: Those aren't OS versions.

Comment: @AndréDion IOS 11.1

Comment: I tried `<ion-col col-3 text-center><img src="./assets/imgs/homer.svg" style="padding:7px;"/>
    <p style="font-size:11px; ">Parking</p></ion-col>` on ios11.1 ionic3 and it worked.

Comment: Issue for me was that the svg image was nested inside <ion-title> tags, which worked fine on Android and in the browser, but iOS didn't want to play nicely with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verified that both of these work on ionic3 / iOS 11.

home.html

```
  <object style="max-width: 100%;" type="image/svg+xml" data="./assets/imgs/homer.svg">
    Your browser does not support SVG
  </object>
  <img style="max-width: 100%;" src="./assets/imgs/homer.svg"/>
```

Comment: For me (ionic 3.9.2) the later option (img tag) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using `property binding` instead of `interpolation`.And also don't use `inline styles`. It will degrade the performance of the app (since no caching on inline styles) and very difficult to maintain the code.

Working [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xvaibt?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

*ts*

```
myImage='./assets/imgs/svg/parking.svg';
```

*html*

```
<ion-col col-3><img type="image/svg+xml" [src]="myImage"/></ion-col>
```

Comment: I get `Cannot read property 'svg' of undefined` and also it gives error on `.`  unexpected template error `"./assets/imgs/svg/parking.svg"`

Comment: do I need to do something on src property binding (typescript file), why do I have that in the first place ?

Comment: Is that working with the simple image? Try that. We always try to use property binding if possible.That is recommended by the Ionic team.

Comment: no same error if I add DOT then dot is the issue if I use assets/imgs/abc.png then png is the issue. I never used property binding for images before. do I miss some libraries or so?

Comment: Yes, can you show me reference in the Ionic Docs which recommends using property binding for src property? I checked here and they dont seem to use it https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/

Comment: See the Update.

Comment: Hey - can you share the inside of those SVGs? like do you have links to external resources there etc. The issue could be the SVG images themselves. Try to use these SVGs in non ionic html and see if you can render those in Safari

Comment: @SergeyRudenko yes now I think its SVG that is causing these issue but it works on android and windows, I dont have a Mac. let me give you the link to one of the SVG's I am using : https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=dresscode&i=126732  Can you share with me one SVG image that would definitely work with Ionic / IOS ?

Comment: @Sampath nope same issue, I cant see the SVG. I tried so many alternatives, now its time to change the SVG itself and try something that is works for others

Comment: @Sampath ofcourse PNG, JPEG, JPG images do work. its just SVG. so I think its SVG issue. Can someone provide me SVG image I can test on?

Comment: Here it is : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xvaibt?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Comment: @Sampath the linux logo tux did not render for some reason. inshort not an SVG issue. I think I am out of ideas, any idea on how to go about this, how can I pinpoint the issue. I dont have Mac or Safari

Comment: @Sampath finally it worked, I directly passed url to the svg. so in my case : I just passed this url : https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/NewTux.svg to the img and it worked. Is this is a good solution? my app is based on restful api service, so do I directly point <img tag to> svg source file on server? or do I get entire SVG and show it on the app? I have 15 to 20 svg max

Comment: OK I cleaned the SVG for you using notepad and removed some of the weird URL links. See if you can reproduce it now?

Comment: @SergeyRuenko will definitely try tomorrow. Its quite late here.

Comment: You have a problem with your `svg`.You can test this.Just download the above `svg` and store it on your `assets` folder and use like this `myImage='./assets/imgs/svg/parking.svg'`. It must work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that the SVGs you are trying to render have a lot of metadata details that prevent normal rendering. Here try cleaner version:

- removed non standard xlmns links
- removed metadata
- added width="100%" and height="100%"

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 125">
  <g>
    <path d="M53.585,18.319L56.849,2H37.233l3.263,16.319H53.585z M54.869,3.622l-2.615,13.075H41.827L39.211,3.622H54.869z"/>
    <path d="M61.738,56.868l3.878-3.879l-11.9-32.728l-0.067-0.625H40.432l-5.955,56.574l-0.028,0.261l12.593,22.036L59.502,76.7   l0.131-0.228l-3.242-30.8l1.667,7.516L61.738,56.868z M47.041,95.238L36.117,76.121l5.775-54.862h10.217l5.856,54.862   L47.041,95.238z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```